# ASP.NET AJAX Server Control - Detecting Instantiation of Control

Tags: asp.net, javascript, controls

I am creating a custom .NET AJAX Server Control, and need to get access to the JavaScript object functionality associated with that control.  I can do this by finding the control in the ScriptManager using the $find method.  However, I need to determine when I can call $find. If I do this on the "onload" event of the body of my HTML page, it can't find the control.  Thus I end up having to locate the control with each event I wire up and my code ends up looking like this:

```
function button1_click() {
    var control = $find("<%=Control.ClientID%>");
    control.DoSomething();
}

function button2_click() {
    var control = $find("<%=Control.ClientID%>");
    control.DoSomethingElse();
}
```

I would rather store that control once, and use it throughout the rest of my event calls.  Thus I'm hoping the code would eventually look something like this:

```
var _control = null;
function load() {
     _control = $find("<%=Control.ClientID%>");
}

function button1_click() {    
    _control.DoSomething();
}

function button2_click() {
    _control.DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't make sense.  I am new at creating these custom controls, so I'm not quite sure of the terminology yet.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "load" DOM event occurs before the ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework is initialized. Client-side controls are initialized by handling the `init` event of the `Sys.Application` object. That's why an ASP.NET Ajax control's initialization script is output like:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create( ... )
});
```

You can use the [load](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/AJAXClientEvents.aspx) event of the `Sys.Application` object or its shortcut- the `pageLoad` method. It occurs after the `init` event and all ASP.NET Ajax controls will be initialized then. Here is some sample code:

```
var _control = null;

function pageLoad() {
    _control = $find("<%= Control1.ClientID %>");
}
```